# What jQuery event handler can be triggered after the deletion of all text in a form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

If all of the text in a form field is selected and then the Backspace or Delete key are used, I want to be able to run some additional code. I have tried using change, blur, keypress, keydown. None seem to work.

Example that doesn't work:

```
$('input[id^=txtDate_]').on('keydown', function() {
    enableSaveChanges();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/6Uq85/

```
$('textarea[name="foo"]').keyup(function(e) {
    var currentText = $(this).val();
    if( 0 == currentText.length && (e.keyCode = 46 || e.keyCode == 8)) {
        console.log('empty');
    }
});
```

I should add that I am a fan of `keyup()` here as the event order for `keypress`,`keydown` and `keyup` are different. You can test to see which makes more sense for you. The reason that I use `keyup` here is because the textarea (or input) isn't actually empty when you press the key.

Comment: `keyup()` worked beautifully! Thanks! I was unaware of the differences between `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup`, but I am bookmarking those pages in the jQuery API docs for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

Use the key codes for 'delete' and 'backspace'

delete = 46

backspace = 8

example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#input').keyup(function(e) {
var str = jQuery('#input').val();
if( (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8) && str == "" ) {
    alert("Hey");
}
```

});

EDITED: check for empty input field

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for

```
<input type="txt" id="txt"/>

$('#test').keyup(function(e){
if($('#test').val() == '' && e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8)){
  console.log('Input is emptied');
 }
});
```